# run Matlab in batch mode

Tags: matlab, command-line, batch-file

It seems to me that there are two ways to run Matlab in batch mode:

the first one:

```
unset DISPLAY  
matlab > matlab.out 2>&1 << EOF  
plot(1:10)  
print file  
exit  
EOF
```

The second one uses option "-r MATLAB_command":

```
matlab -nojvm -nosplash -r MyCommand
```

Are these two equivalent?

What does "<< EOF" and the last "EOF" mean in the first method?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first method simply [redirects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)#Redirecting_to_and_from_the_standard_file_handles) the standard output `> matlab.out` and the standard error `2>&1` to the file `matlab.out`.

Then it uses the [heredoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) way of passing input to MATLAB (this is not specific to MATLAB, it is a method of passing multiple lines as input to command line programs in general).

The syntax is `<<` followed by an unique identifier, then your text, finally the unique id to finish.
You can try this on the shell:

```
cat << END
some
text
multiple lines
END
```

The second method of using the `-r` option starts MATLAB and execute the statement passed immediately. It could be some commands or the name of a script or function found on the path.
It is equivalent to doing something like:

```
python -c "print 'hello world'"
```

Refer to this [page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlablinux.html) for a list of the other start options.