# Matlab: Running an m-file from command-line

Tags: matlab, command-line, automation

Suppose that;

I have an m-file at location:
`C:\M1\M2\M3\mfile.m`

And exe file of the matlab is at this location:
`C:\E1\E2\E3\matlab.exe`

I want to run this m-file with Matlab, from command-line, for example inside a .bat file. How can I do this, is there a way to do it?

Comment: you might find these useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495/how-can-i-stop-matlab-from-returning-until-after-a-command-line-script-completes, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857825/run-matlab-in-batch-mode

Answer (score 129, accepted):

A command like this runs the m-file successfully:

`"C:\<a long path here>\matlab.exe" -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r "run('C:\<a long path here>\mfile.m'); exit;"`

Comment: Another similar question is here to reply : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25102699/open-a-gui-directly-from-desktop-shortcut-in-matlab-enviroment

Comment: That would be good if you add "exit" command at the end to make your answer more practical and helpful.

Comment: The single and double quotation marks in and around the "run" command are important!

Comment: What if you want to pass arguments?

Comment: Does the Windows version support the -nodesktop option?  I thought not, but may be wrong.

Comment: Note that `-r` is [no longer recommended as of R2019b](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58358304/7328782).

Comment: This looks like the solution I'm searching for but I get "undefined variable or class" error on myFile.m.  I'm in the directory of my .m file.  The error is on this part "run(myFile.m); exit"

Comment: Update: Figured out that I needed to remove the .m from the command.  So this worked for me: "C:\<a long path here>\matlab.exe" -nosplash -nodesktop -r "mfile; exit;"

Answer (score 72):

I think that one important point that was not mentioned in the previous answers is that, if not explicitly indicated, the matlab interpreter will remain open.
Therefore, to the answer of @hkBattousai I will add the `exit` command:

`"C:\<a long path here>\matlab.exe" -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r "run('C:\<a long path here>\mfile.m');exit;"`

Comment: For some reason if `mfile.m` triggers an error the explicit `exit` function is never called, making the whole process wait...

Answer (score 46):

Here is what I would use instead, to gracefully handle errors from the script:

```
"C:\<a long path here>\matlab.exe" -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r "try, run('C:\<a long path here>\mfile.m'), catch, exit, end, exit"
```

If you want more verbosity:

```
"C:\<a long path here>\matlab.exe" -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r "try, run('C:\<a long path here>\mfile.m'), catch me, fprintf('%s / %s\n',me.identifier,me.message), end, exit"
```

I found the original reference [here](http://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/247486). Since original link is now gone, here is the link to an alternate newreader still alive today:

- [exit matlab when running batch m file](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.matlab/GnO_vHvDGjA/eiDucyPs8IMJ)

Answer (score 30):

On Linux you can do the same and you can actually send back to the shell a custom error code, like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
matlab -nodisplay -nojvm -nosplash -nodesktop -r \ 
      "try, run('/foo/bar/my_script.m'), catch, exit(1), end, exit(0);"
echo "matlab exit code: $?"
```

it prints `matlab exit code: 1` if the script throws an exception, `matlab exit code: 0` otherwise.

Comment: To display the error as MATLAB would do when not catching it, just do

`"try, run('/foo/bar/my_script.m'), catch e, disp(getReport(e)), exit(1), end, exit(0);"`

Answer (score 19):

Since R2019b, there is a new command line option, `-batch`. It replaces `-r`, which is no longer recommended. It also unifies the syntax across platforms. See for example [the documentation for Windows](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabwindows.html), for the other platforms the description is identical.

```sh
matlab -batch "statement to run"
```

This starts MATLAB without the desktop or splash screen, logs all output to `stdout` and `stderr`, exits automatically when the statement completes, and provides an exit code reporting success or error.

It is thus no longer necessary to use `try`/`catch` around the code to run, and it is no longer necessary to add an `exit` statement.

Comment: This seems to work well most of the time, but running `matlab -batch "disp('hello')"` on Windows with R2021b prints "hello" and then a Java error `Caused by: com.mathworks.util.ShutdownRuntimeException: Java is shutting down`.

Comment: @PaulWintz That sounds like something you should report as a bug to the MathWorks. You can probably circumvent that with `matlab -nojvm -batch "..."`, so that the Java VM is never started.

Comment: @Chis Luengo, including `-nojvm` does prevent the error. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Here are the steps:

1. Start the command line.
2. Enter the folder containing the .m file with `cd C:\M1\M2\M3`
3. Run the following: `C:\E1\E2\E3\matlab.exe -r mfile`

Windows systems will use your **current folder** as the location for MATLAB to search for .m files, and the `-r` option tries to start the given .m file as soon as startup occurs.

Comment: It won't run inside a .bat file. I gave it as an example. Actually, I will run it by the Win32 API function `CreateProcessW()`.

Answer (score 13):

```
cat 1.m | matlab -nodesktop -nosplash
```

And I use Ubuntu

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to malat. Your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32568956/5060036) helped me. 
But I want to add my try-catch block, as I found the `MExeption` method `getReport()` that returns the whole error message and prints it to the matlab console.

Additionally I printed the filename as this compilation is part of a batch script that calls matlab.

```
try
    some_code
    ...
catch message
    display(['ERROR in file: ' message.stack.file])
    display(['ERROR: ' getReport(message)])
end;
```

For a false model name passed to legacy code generation method, the output would look like:

```
ERROR in file: C:\..\..\..
ERROR: Undefined function or variable 'modelname'.

Error in sub-m-file (line 63)
legacy_code( 'slblock_generate', specs, modelname);

Error in m-file (line 11)
sub-m-file

Error in run (line 63)
evalin('caller', [script ';']);
```

Finally, to display the output at the windows command prompt window, just log the matlab console to a file with `-logfile logfile.txt` (use additionally `-wait`) and call the batch command `type logfile.txt`

Answer (score 3):

I run this command within a bash script, in particular to submit SGE jobs and batch process things:

```
/Path_to_matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop < m_file.m
```

Answer (score 1):

Since none of the answers has information about feeding input argument, it is important to 
add it here. After some research, I found this [link](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/39067-run-matlab-function-with-arguments-on-linux-terminal)

Feeding the arguments is very similar to how we run a Matlab function.

```
matlab -r 'try myfunction(argument1,argument2); catch; end; quit'
```

If you are somehow getting an argument from bash/terminal, you simply need to insert that into the bash command as:

```
matlab -r 'try myfunction($MY_BASH_ARG,argument2); catch; end; quit'
```

(This is after a couple of trial and error)

Comment: You can use `matlab -r "addpath('/my/mfile/directory/'); my_mfilename(argument1, argument2)"` so you don't have to rely on the working directory which can be reset by `startup.m`

Answer (score 0):

In the new releases of matlab, there is no need to specify the option "-nodisplay" in the command line mentioned by the accepted answer. Simply doing the following will work without any warning:

```
"C:\...\matlab.exe" -nosplash -nodesktop -r "run('<matlab-script>.m'); exit;"
```

Comment: In the new releases, use the `-batch` option, `-r` is no longer recommended. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58358304/7328782