# calling matlab from perl using a script

Tags: matlab, perl

I would like to know how one could call MATLAB from a Perl script?
To be exact, I want to run a *.m file with

```
a = zeros(10)
```

from Perl. by the way, I am using Eclipse as an IDE for Perl.

I searched for a while, but could not find a clear answer.
Please help!

Comment: There are several PerlMonks nodes about this: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=642247, http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=818233

Comment: See also [Running an m-file from command-line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657005/matlab-running-an-m-file-from-command-line), and [Start MATLAB program from Linux system prompt](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlablinux.html)

Comment: or https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::Matlab::Local

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Thanks a lot! I found out the solution as you both mentioned in the links and then I am posting it here.

Comment: @jm666 Thanks a lot! I found out the solution as you both mentioned in the links and then I am posting it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could write here an *.m file for Matlab without using Matlab text editor or just comment the following lines till line `EOF`.

Start to write into 'Call_mfile.m' all lines after `print $matlab <<EOF;`

```
open(my $matlab, '>', 'Call_mfile.m');
print $matlab <<EOF;

 close all;
 clear all;
 clc;

% write here your Matlab code
a = zeros(10)

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
EOF
###########################################################################
# Use this command when you want to update your toolbox
#system('matlab rehash toolboxcache')

# Use this when you want to use Java interface!
# Notice!!
#    This could not then open another files which are called in Call_mfile.m 
#    file. Otherwise use the next command!

#system('matlab -nojvm -r Call_mfile');
system('matlab -r Call_mfile');
```