# How to open a matlab program using windows command prompt? (in a single window)

Tags: matlab, command-prompt

I have managed to open a Matlab file in the Windows command prompt, but the problem is that every time I repeat the the command in Windows command prompt a new window of matlab is being opened and then the program is being executed. Is there any way to open a single Matlab application and then execute a number of commands in a single window? Please help me.

Comment: You can group your commands into one script and run that.

Comment: Please read the tag description before using them, removed unrelated tags.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657005/matlab-running-an-m-file-from-command-line