# command-line matlab script calls give undefined variable/class errors

Tags: matlab

I'm working with a command line Matlab (i.e. remote ubuntu linux workstation) and am trying to execute a script.

When I ran:

```
matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -r "my_script.m"
```

matlab would open and give me an error message stating

```
Undefined variable "my_script" or class "my_script.m"
```

I found a thread on stackoverflow with a user having a similar problem: 
[Matlab: Running an m-file from command-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657005/matlab-running-an-m-file-from-command-line)

but when I attempted to implement the suggested syntax:

```
matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -r "run('my_script.m');"
```

I now get a syntax error,

```
Unexpected MATLAB expression.

Error in run (line 96)
evalin('caller', [script ';'])
```

I seldom use Matlab and even more rarely do so w/o a gui, so I've been trying without success to fix the syntax using information from online messageboards.

Comment: Most likely my_script.m is not on your Matlab path, so it cannot find it. Add it to your path and/or switch current directory before trying to run the script.

Comment: I checked that with pwd in an open matlab session. The working directory is where my_script.m is located

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to remove `.m` extension:

```
matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -r "my_script"
```

The reason is that `my_script.m` is not a valid Matlab statement. In order to run a script / function you need to execute it using its name, i.e. `my_script`. You can see that if you try running `my_script.m` and `my_script` statements right from Matlab command window.

The second error you mention (when using `run` command) seems to be the actual error in your script. It seems like you forgot to copy-paste the very top line which should show the line number where the error occurs. What you see below, i.e. `Error in run (line 96)` and `evalin('caller', [script ';'])` is just a second entry in the stack trace. It does confirm the the error occurs while evaluating your script using `evalin`.

Comment: @Max also, note that this means "open a matlab session and run the script", not "run the script and exit". Your matlab session will remain open. If you just want to run the script and exit, then do `-r "myscript; exit"`