# Return value when calling matlab

Tags: matlab, powershell

When I call MATLAB from PowerShell, it works fine:

```
$command = "path-to-matlab.exe"
$args = "-nosplash -nodesktop -r run('path-to-my-mfile.m');exit();"
$process = Start-Process -Wait -PassThru $command $args
write-output $process.ExitCode
```

(Similar to [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657005/matlab-running-an-m-file-from-command-line))

However, when there's an error in MATLAB, how can PowerShell know?

I tried `exit(1)` from MATLAB, but the variable `$process.ExitCode` still returns `0`.

I also tried `fprintf('some error message')` from within MATLAB, but it doesn't get printed to the PowerShell console, but only printed in MATLAB window.

Answer (score 0):

What you'll want to do is wrap the function in a `try` `catch` block in order to see if it returned any errors.  Your code should end up looking like this:

```
$command = "path-to-matlab.exe"
$args = "-nosplash -nodesktop -r run('path-to-my-mfile.m');exit();"
try {
  $process = Start-Process -Wait -PassThru $command $args
  Write-Host "Success!"
}
catch {
  $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
  return $ErrorMessage
  pause
}
```