# MATLAB R2020a run .m script from terminal

Tags: matlab

I want to execute a matlab script from the terminal.

Although there are many questions (e.g.: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657005/matlab-running-an-m-file-from-command-line) or [here](https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/8345-running-scripts-from-command-line)) and answers out there, I still could not find a solution how to get it working.

I'm currently in the same directory as a `test.m` script and following the answers found on the internet, I have tried to start matlab using:

```
matlab -nodesktop -nodisplay -nosplash -r test
```

From the matlab [help](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlablinux.html), I think the right approach would be to use the -batch flag

```
matlab -batch "test"
```

but also this does not work.

I also tried several alternatives:

```
matlab -nodesktop -nodisplay -nosplash -r "test"
matlab -nodesktop -nodisplay -nosplash -r "test.m"
matlab -nodesktop -nodisplay -nosplash -batch "test.m"
matlab -nodesktop -nodisplay -nosplash -r "run('test')"
matlab -nodesktop -nodisplay -nosplash -r "run('test.m')"
matlab -nodesktop -nodisplay -nosplash -r "run('/absolut/path/test')"
```

However, I always get the following error message:

```
                           < M A T L A B (R) >
                  Copyright 1984-2020 The MathWorks, Inc.
              R2020a Update 3 (9.8.0.1396136) 64-bit (glnxa64)
                                May 27, 2020

 
To get started, type doc.
For product information, visit www.mathworks.com.
 
Warning: Command line argument -r cannot be combined with subsequent -r
argument.
```

What is working on Linux is

```
matlab -nodisplay < test.m
```

Edit: I tested it today on windows and

```
matlab -batch test
```

works on windows.

Comment: On Linux, try `which matlab`, and see if it’s an alias or a script that you (your IT dept?) made to run some command on startup. This would be the only way you would see what you’re seeing.

Comment: `which matlab` returns `/usr/bin/matlab`

Comment: Ok. Did you open that file in a text editor? Does it add a `-r` parameter to the executable?

Comment: that is it. I did not realize that this is only a text file. There they added a -r flag

Comment: There you go. Now you can see how to call the “real” MATLAB program, bypassing this script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message you're getting there indicates that somehow you've ended up with two `-r` specifications, as if you'd called `matlab -r test -r test`. Are you sure you don't have an alias or similar for `matlab`?

In any case, as per the [doc](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlablinux.html), the `-r` is no longer recommended, you should use `-batch`, and the argument needs to be a *statement*, not a path to a file. So, you *should* use

```
matlab -sd /absolut/path -batch test
```

The `-sd` parameter sets the starting directory for MATLAB so it can find "test.m". With `-batch`, the `-nodesktop`, `-nodisplay`, and `-nosplash` are implied.

Comment: If I enter 'type matlab' the output is 'matlab is bashed (/usr/bin/matlab)' thus, I do not think that there is an alias. I tested it today on windows and `matlab -batch test` works there. But no luck on Linux so far.

Comment: How strange. The syntax I posted definitely works correctly, and the error you get definitely occurs for me if I use `-r` twice, so something is wrong _somewhere_.

Comment: Are you testing it on Linux? (Ubuntu 18.04 with R2020a)?

Comment: Yes, I've just checked R2020a using Debian 10.

Comment: I just tried it on a different computer running R2019a with the same problem. 'matlab -batch pwd' is not working there as well - maybe it has to do with how our IT installed matlab? but I'm unsure

Comment: Maybe try `set -x` in a shell before you start? Might show if there's anything untoward.