# Is there a matlab equivalent of Rscript?

Tags: matlab

`R` can be run on the command line in at least two ways. One is to use the interactive interpreter, by typing `R` on the command line. Another is to run a script and quit, by using `Rscript Foo.r`.  Is it possible to run `matlab`  in a mode where it runs  a script and quits?

I apologize if this is a newb question but I googled around, and tried to do `matlab --help` and `man matlab`, and I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Use `run(filename)` or `echodemo filename` in the command line.

You can also run this command:

```
C:\<a long path here>\matlab.exe" -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r "run('C:\<a long path here>\filename.m');
```

You can refer to details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857825/run-matlab-in-batch-mode) to run matlab in batch mode too.